# Iterating store in relay optimisticUpdater

Tags: react-native, relayjs, relay

*Apologies in advance, I'm new to relay and not sure I've got all the terminology here right...*

I have a (simplified) graph that looks like:

```
customer {
  summary(id: "ABC123") {
    records { // This is an array of Record
      tag
    }
  }
}
```

`Customer`, `Summary` and `Record` are all objects with global IDs - they show up as records in the Relay DevTools inspector.

I have a mutation that removes a tag by name (from elsewhere in the graph - not shown), from which I need to update the customer summary object to remove the record with associated tag. I have tried two approaches and not gotten very far with either:

1. Re-request `customer.summary` as part of the mutation. The problem is I don't know what the ID is at that point. (Maybe I can thread it through some how, but that would be messy.) Also doesn't really solve the problem, since I'd like to do this optimistically.
2. In an optimistic updater, remove any tag record that matches. This seems like it should work, but the [RecordProxy](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/en/relay-store#recordproxy) doesn't appear to have a rich enough API to enable me to do this.

First approach, I can't seem to get access to the summary record via the root:

```
const customer = store.getRoot().getLinkedRecord('customer') // works!
customer.getLinkedRecord("summary") // undefined
customer.getLinkedRecord("summary", {id: "ABC123"}) // undefined
```

Second approach, if I could ask the store for "all records of type" or even "all records" I could iterate through and find the one I need to edit, but this doesn't seem to be a method that's exposed (even though Relay DevTools must be doing it somehow).